# latex bibliography problem, it was working fine with natbib, not working with biblatex

Tags: latex, biblatex

Good afternoon,

I have a problem with bibliography, it worked ok with natbib, but unfortunately now I need to use biblatex, with ''phys'' style and I get some errors, it doesn't work anymore. This is the code, sorry for long preamble...

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{book}  % default square logo 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utopia]{quotchap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{siunitx}




  \usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=phys,
  ]{biblatex}

 \addbibresource{References}



\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=foo, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, plainpages=false, pdfpagelabels=true, urlcolor=blue}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\title{Manipulation of SPEs}   %note \\[1ex] is a line break in the title
\author{Nicola}             %your name
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{25}{19}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{12}{17}}
\newcommand{\ssecfnt}{\fontsize{12}{14}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\chapfnt\bfseries}
{\Large\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{10pt}{\chapfnt}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\def\baselinestretch{2} 
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{15pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{13pt}{14pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{{\fontsize{8}{20} \selectfont\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\fontsize{8}{20} \selectfont\leftmark}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1cm}




\begin{document}

    \baselineskip=18pt plus1pt
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \maketitle                  



\include{Abstract}




        \tableofcontents            

    \include{Intro/Chapter1} 
    \include{chapter2/Chapter2} 
    \include{chapter3/Chapter3} 
    \include{chapter4/Chapter4} 
    \include{chapter5/Chapter5} 
    \include{Conclusions}
    \include{ChapterPublications}
    \include{ChapterAcknowledgements}

    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}



    \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

When I compile the file with bibtex I get the following error:

Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: Thesis-Nicola.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: Abstract.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: Intro/Chapter1.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter2/Chapter2.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter3/Chapter3.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter4/Chapter4.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter5/Chapter5.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: Conclusions.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: ChapterPublications.aux A level-1 auxiliary file: ChapterAcknowledgements.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file Thesis-Nicola.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Thesis-Nicola.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Thesis-Nicola.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?
Thank you very much,
Nicola.

Comment: You are using biblatex with the `biber` backend. You must compile with `biber` and not with `bibtex`

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much! Your answer was to the point! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The error message you get shows that you are using `bibtex` to compile your bibliography.

However you are using `biblatex` with the `biber` backend. This means that you need to compile with `biber` instead if `bibtex`